# Date Calendar doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a .js file with the datepicker function (code given below). And I have a textbox in my aspx code that needs to get the calendar on select. I put a breakpoint in my js file and it doesn't hit file when I debug my code. Can you please help?

Picker.js file:

```
function () {
    $("#ToTextBox").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
}
```

Aspx code:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="ToTextBox" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Does it show some JS error at browser's console?

Comment: No it doesn't. The textbox doesn't show the calendar. Using IE10 browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS code it's not being executing when DOM is loaded, you have to wrap it in a `$()` object like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#ToDateTextBox").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

So it applies the datepicker after the website is loaded.

Comment: Are you including jQuery main file? If so and the problem persits, change any '$' with jQuery, like this: jQuery(function() ....